# T-SQL - Creating Graph from data in View

Tags: t-sql

I'm fairly new to T-SQL, Stored Procedures and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I have created a View in my database called BodyBasics. In this View, there is a column called BackAngle. In the BackAngle column, I list at which angle the users back is bent. The datatype is float and can range from 90 to 180.

Some example values found in this View column are:

```
173,10786534157, 147,423570266, 170,196359990068, 148,774131860277, 153,439316876929, 147,063469480619, 173,861485242977, 172,1319088368, 145,416983331938, 163,02645970309, 147,65814822779, 146,212510299859, 173,769456580658
```

The View looks like this:

```
| ID | Timestamp | RecordingId | BodyNumber | BackAngle |
```

What I would like to do is SELECT the BackAngle data from the View in chronological order and plot the data into a graph.

The query I have tried is:

```
GO
DECLARE @BackAngle TABLE(Backangle FLOAT);

INSERT @BackAngle(Backangle) SELECT dbo.ViewBodies.BackAngle FROM dbo.ViewBodies
WHERE dbo.ViewBodies.BackAngle IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Timestamp;
SELECT geometry::STGeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(' + @BackAngle(Backangle) + ')' );
GO
```

The errors that I get from this code is:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'Backangle'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

I got the geometry::STGeomFromText syntax from this article:
http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/generating-charts-and-drawings-sql-server-management-studio

Can someone point out what is wrong with my code and whether this is the right way to do this? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Please give some examples of the values you have there in `BackAngle`. There's no need to fill a declared table first. You could just call the function *directly*...

Comment: Some examples: 173,10786534157, 147,423570266, 170,196359990068, 148,774131860277, 153,439316876929, 147,063469480619, 173,861485242977, 172,1319088368, 145,416983331938, 163,02645970309, 147,65814822779
146,212510299859, 173,769456580658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a temp table you should make a TEXT STRING with variables to use it in LINESTRING. As a scale line you can use row numbers (1,2,3,4,...)

```
DECLARE @WKT AS VARCHAR(8000);
 SET @WKT =
              STUFF(
                    (SELECT ',' 
                            + CAST( ROW_NUMBER() 
                                    OVER (ORDER BY [timestamp]) AS VARCHAR(100)) 
                            + ' ' + CAST( BackAngle AS VARCHAR(30) )
                     FROM ViewBodies
                     WHERE BackAngle IS NOT NULL
                     ORDER BY [timestamp]
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SELECT geometry::STGeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(' + @WKT + ')', 0 );
```